# Как реализовать постоянный процесс парсинга?

Tags: python

Есть скрипт парсящий информацию с обновляемой страницы и кладущий её в бд. Сейчас он срабатывает только после принудительного запуска через терминал, отрабатывает цикл и выключается. Как реализовать постоянную работу процесса, с срабатыванием цикла на парсинг каждые 5 минут, например? Спасибо

Comment: Почему не запустить в цикле с ожиданием 5 мин?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если вы используете linux, то можно запустить скрипт через cron:

```
0 */5 * ? * * ~/script.sh
```

Этот код будет запускать ваш скрипт каждые пять минут. Что это такое и как использовать код приведенный выше, можно прочесть здесь https://help.ubuntu.ru/wiki/cron

Если Windows, то используйте планировщик задач [docs.microsoft.com](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/cc721871(v%3Dws.11))
Русскоязычную статью о том как им пользоваться можно найти здесь https://remontka.pro/windows-task-scheduler/

Comment: А если планирую запускать на винде? С помощью чего реализовать средствами самого Питона?

Comment: Добавил в ответ информацию по windows. Средствами самого питона тоже можно реализовать, но намного правильнее будет использовать планировщик задач

Comment: Запустите парсер в цикле while как вариант

Comment: @danilshik В этом случае придется следить за выполнением этого цикла, чтобы успеть его перезапустить в случае чего.

Comment: Так он на следующем шаге сам запустится)

Comment: Нет, если нет обработки ошибок. В том числе может случиться что-то с самим компьютером и он будет перезагружен. Такой способ тоже имеет место быть, но проблем меньше будет с планировщиком задач.